# How do you determine the file name of a database?

Tags: sqlanywhere

My application uses Entity Framework 4 to access a SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 database.  I need a query that will tell me what the name of the database file on disk, including the drive letter.

How do I get the database path from the database itself?

Comment: Could this help? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/17/sql-server-find-current-location-of-data-and-log-file-of-all-the-database/

Comment: That article is for SQL Server.  I'm using SQL Anywhere.  Different database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  This query will retrieve the path of the file that the current database is stored in:

SELECT file_name FROM SYSDBFILE WHERE dbfile_name = 'system'